# Indesign CS6: Cannot add alt tags to images

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6

I am developing a flyer that will be distributed as a PDF, and our requirement is that it be "Section 508" compliant, that is, readable by a screen reader. I am trying to add alt tags to meet this requirement, but when I go to **Object** -> **Object Export Options** and click on the **Alt Text** tab, the **Alt Text Source** pull-down menu is greyed out and does not allow me to do anything.

Does anyone have any idea of what is wrong here?

Comment: Two things that come to mind: **1.** Maybe you have the actual image selected, not the image frame. **2.** It could be possible that you don't have anything selected, while you have that Object export options window` open.

Comment: It appears you asked and received an answer here: http://forums.adobe.com/message/6333851?tstart=0 if you could be so kind as to leave what worked for you and mark it answered, it would help others that might come across this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took two steps to resolve my issue, although I am not sure that the first step was necessary.

1. I trashed my InDesign settings per the guidance here: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/526990
2. I discovered that I was incorrect in trying to set the alt tag on the image itself; like @joonas suggested above, the frame must be selected for alt tags, and not the image itself.